# Hyperparameters tuning with tf.estimator.DNNClassifier

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-estimator

I've implemented the following model using the DNNClassifier class. The model is parametrized as follows

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
       hidden_units=[60, 30, 20],
       feature_columns=feature_columns,
       n_classes=len(labels),
       label_vocabulary=labels,
       batch_norm=True,
       optimizer=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
           learning_rate=tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay(
               learning_rate=0.1,
               global_step=tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step(),
               decay_steps=10000,
               decay_rate=0.96)
       )
)
```

Now I would like to do some hyperparameters tuning (e.g. learning rate, number of units, etc).

`DNNClassifier`, being a premade estimator class, inherits from the `Estimator` class.

But while `Estimator` has a `params` argument to pass hyperparameters, `DNNClassifier` has none.

So what should be the preferred way to do hyperparameter tuning using `DNNClassifier`?

Comment: But you are already passing both the hyperparams to your model already. You are passing number of units in `hidden_units` and learning rate in `optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)=0.1`. Could you describe your question again?

Comment: Yes, the model is already parametrized with fixed values. My goal now is to do some hyperparameter tuning on few values. I rephrased the question. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need an **input function** for your estimator, assuming you are using pandas dataframes to keep your data, *(data_df and label_df are dataframes)* you can write something like:

```
def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
    def input_function():
        ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))
        if shuffle:
            ds = ds.shuffle(1024)
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
        return ds

    return input_function
```

Then use the code above to create two input functions, one for training and one for validation like this:

```
train_input_fn = make_input_fn(X_train, y_train)
val_input_fn = make_input_fn(X_val, y_val, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
```

Finally **train** the classifier you defined and **evaluate** it using the validation set. Run this pipeline multiple times to tune your **hyperparameters**.

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
       hidden_units=[60, 30, 20],
       feature_columns=feature_columns,
       n_classes=len(labels),
       label_vocabulary=labels,
       batch_norm=True,
       optimizer=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
           learning_rate=tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay(
               learning_rate=0.1,
               global_step=tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step(),
               decay_steps=10000,
               decay_rate=0.96)
       )
)
# Train Classifier.
classifier.train(train_input_fn)

# Evaluate Classifier.
result = classifier.evaluate(val_input_fn)
print(result)
```